# How to get a list of all ImageFields not found/saved on the server?

Tags: mysql, linux, django, centos

So I have a table of 40,000 photos. They've all been saved, but for some of them, when I use their path in the table, the image is not actually saved on the server.

This only happens some of the time, so I want to get a list of all these photos, so I can fetch them and manually save them on my server.

I want to either get the IDs of these photos, or some sort of identifier, because in my table, I also have the source URL of the image, so it's just a matter of using `wget` on all of the source URLs to download them all.

So for example, the table may have 3 rows:

```
photos/abc.jpg
photos/def.jpg
photos/ghi.jpg
```

`photos/abc.jpg` will be found, `photos/def.jpg` will be found but `photos/ghi.jpg` will not be found in the photos folder, when it should be.

How do I get a list of all the image names or IDs that cannot be found on the server at the specified location in the ImageField.

Comment: What's your question then?

Comment: @ShangWang added more details

Answer (score 0):

Just make a loop with data from DB and then check if file exists with function

```
file_exists()
```

If that function return false so file not found on server you can just add it to array and than you have list of all db records without files on server

Comment: Django is a Python language. I don't know PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Tra this

```
#change to the directory where dir photo is

$ cd /xx/yy
$ find photos/ -name \*.[Jj][Pp][Gg] -exec echo "insert IGNORE into tmptable VALUE(\"{}\");" \; >images.sql

# now you have a file image.sql where all insert in
# like:
# insert IGNORE into tmptable VALUE("photo/aa.jpg");
# insert IGNORE into tmptable VALUE("photo/aaac.jpg");

# Start mysql client

$ mysql -uroot -pXXXXXXX
> use yourDatabase;

# create a Table

> CREATE TABLE `tmptable` (
  `image` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `d` (`image`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

# Import the file

> \. images.sql

# Now you can select the tmptable and join your table to find your missing images
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the table and check for each item, if there is a file for it.

If there is no file found, then download it from the source (and then wait for two seconds after each download, you don't want to flood the source server).

```
import urllib

for pic in Pictures.objects.all():
    if not pic.get_filename().exists():
        url = pic.get_source_url()
        urllib.urlretrieve(url, filename=pic.get_filename())
```

Add your own `get_filename()` and `get_source_url()` methods.

Since this is a Django question: you may want to make this [a management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-management-commands/#management-commands-and-locales) for your Django app, so in the future, you can easily run it from the CLI or even via a cronjob, to automatically fix missing images.